# Saving a column from a file to a list

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to read only 1 column from `file` and save it in the list `column`. I have this code and I don't know how to optimize it. It takes lots of time because I need to call it a lot of times.

```
column = (sum(1 for line in open(file) if line.strip("\n")))*[0]
counter_row = 0
counter_column = 0
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        row = row.strip("\n")
        if row:
            for el_column in row.split(","):
                if counter_column==n_column:
                     column[counter_row]=el_column
                counter_column = counter_column + 1
        counter_row = counter_row + 1
        counter_column = 0
```

Comment: Are you also reading each file multiple times to grab different columns?  For example, do you read files A,B and C to get column 1, and then read them all again to get column 2, and so on?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your biggest problem is the first line:

> ```
> column = (sum(1 for line in open(file) if line.strip("\n")))*[0]
> ```

Opening the file twice is a bad idea for performance, probably much worse than not knowing how large of a list to allocate.  Furthermore, that statement only allocates one element per *non-empty* line, whereas the `counter_row` counts *every* line in the file.  So, the code would crash with an `IndexError` if there are any empty lines.

The inner `for` loop is just a complicated way to do indexing.

Assuming that you want empty lines to be represented by `0`, you could write:

```
column = []
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        row = line.strip("\n")
        column.append(row.split(",")[n_column] if row else 0)
```

If you don't need to test for empty lines, then you could just write:

```
with open(file) as f:
    column = [line.strip("\n").split(",")[n_column] for line in f]
```

You should consider using the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, though, which can handle CSV quoting properly.

Answer (score 7):

It's hard to follow the code when it has no comments.  I'll take a stab at it, though.

It looks like you read through each file twice; once to count the number of lines and once to process each line.  That is very wasteful.

The inner for loop works through each column to find one, you could simply index.

```
column = []
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        row = row.strip("\n")
        if ',' in row:
            column.append( row.split(",")[n_column] )
        else:
            column.append( 0 );
```

If you are reading files multiple time to read successive columns, you could read all columns in one pass, instead.

```
# I'm going to assume each file has a fixed number of columns
N_COL = 5

columns = [[]] * N_COL               # N_COL empty columns
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        row = row.strip("\n")
        if ',' in row:
            values = row.split(",")  # break each row into N_COL values
        else:
            values = [0]*N_COL       # blank row treated as N_COL zeros

        # append the i'th value to the i'th column
        for i in range(N_COL)):
            columns[i].append( values[i] )
```

After this `columns[0]` is the first column of values, `columns[1]` the second, and so forth.

This might not work if there a a huge number of files, or each file is huge.  You might run out of memory to hold all the data.

Comment: If `n_column` is the last column, then the newlines will get copied.